# Setting up a Paypal payment page on site - iframe guide?

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have a shareware site where the user pays $25 for an annual membership. The shareware is free, the membership entitles users to support and an enhanced version of the shareware.

I would like to create a page on my site where the user can make a Paypal payment without leaving the site. Then, I want the user to land on a specific thank you page.

I'm not able to find documentation on how to do this, other than this intimidating, 256 page guide: [Gateway Developer Guide and Reference](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf).

My needs are humble. I'm hoping there is a quick-start guide I missed.

Please advise.

PS: I do have the Paypal Advanced ($5/month).

Comment: odesk, elance etc are the perfect place for this.

Comment: easy, you can't frame paypal, its a security issue. is there any particular reason you want to do it differently then many other thousands of sites? your *needs are humble* do it the standard way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely do not want to leave the page you will need to use [PayPal Payments Advanced](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced) Or [PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro)

Advanced comes with a $5 monthly fee and you will see PayPal branding, (I believe this is almost like an iFrame), however I have never used this service so cannot comment on what is required.

Pro is $30/month however you will not see PayPal branding and user will have no idea PayPal is being used in the backend
This uses an API that you are going to have to do progamming for since it is all done in the backend, and you are also most likely going to want an SSL Certificate.

There is PayPal Payments standard, but that puts a button on your page which redirects you to PayPal. Your customers will not need a PayPal account to pay. This option is free (aside from regular PayPal fees)

There is also PayPal Express Checkout, I am not 100% sure what the difference between this and Payments Standard is.. perhaps a PayPal account is required?

Comment: I've got the Paypal Payments Advanced at $5 a month.  I don't need the Pro - I want people to see the Paypal branding - it's a trusted brand. 

I've got the paypal button right now, but that takes users off my site and doesn't give me the option of a thank-you page on my site.

Comment: Oh ok, it wasn't clear in your post. Have you checked out this link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

Comment: That's not exactly the way I wanted to do it, but this solution will meet my requirements and it is within my skill level. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal have prohibited the page from being included in an iframe, by setting the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header.

There is no way around this security measure.

You could provide a link to go back to your site if you want payment running through PayPal.